# Display random element from XML in TextView of iPhone

Tags: iphone, xml, xcode, sdk, xml-parsing

I am working on something to do a daily verse from the Bible, and I'd like it to be random.  I have an xml of verses which looks like this:

```
<bible translation="KJV">
<testament name="Old">

    <book name="Genesis">
        <chapter number="1">
            <verse number="1">In the beginning God created the heaven and the earth.</verse>
            <verse number="2">And the earth was without form, and void; and darkness was upon the face of the deep. And the Spirit of God moved upon the face of the waters.    </verse>

<!-- THE REST OF THE XML HERE -->

                     </chapter>
             </book>
   </testament>
```

I would like to use a parser to create a NSString of text from one of the verses, but as they are all listed as  there could be several of each of those elements, and are all named differently.  Any suggestions for how I could do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a plist instead of the XML implementation.  I find plists easy to implement and manage.

You could load your plist into a dictionary and then randomly select from there.

Comment: Is there a simple way for converting the xml into a plist?  That's the only thing is either finding a plist of the bible, or an easy way to convert one

Comment: A plist is formatted pretty similarly to XML.  View the text format of the plist and you will see it wont be too bad.